# Row not containing elements when page loads in iOS Safari - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

As it says in the title, a row on my site is not containing its elements properly when the site loads on my iPhone. It works in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari desktop when I change the viewport width, and when I test it in dev tools.

Here's a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Here's a link to the site: www.appepic.com

This is the first time I've built a website using Bootstrap, so I apologize if I missed something simple.

Thank you! Here's the html for reference as well:

```html
<div class="row" id="clients">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h2 class="heading text-uppercase">Brands That Trust AppEpic</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <img src="http://appepic.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Microsoft_logo-200.png" class="center-block brand" id="microsoft">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <img src="http://appepic.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Amazon-logo-200.png" class="center-block brand" id="amazon">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <img src="http://appepic.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/semanoor-logo.png" class="center-block brand" id="semanoor">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Anchors for same site linking-->

  <a name="youthability-test"></a>
  <a name="feedback-panel-test"></a>

  <!--End anchors-->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.container` `div` should be outside (parent) of the `.row` `div`